# Assign index as id to each element of a specific array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have an input JSON :

```json
{
  "a": "foo",
  "bunch": 123,
  "of": "foo",
  "other": "foo",
  "keys": 123,
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "a": "foo",
      "bunch": 123,
      "of": "foo",
      "other": "foo",
      "keys": 123
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "a": "foo",
      "bunch": 123,
      "of": "foo",
      "other": "foo",
      "keys": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

Under the `contacts` array, I'd like to assign an array index to the `id` field, such that the expected output is:

```json
{
  "a": "foo",
  "bunch": 123,
  "of": "foo",
  "other": "foo",
  "keys": 123,
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "a": "foo",
      "bunch": 123,
      "of": "foo",
      "other": "foo",
      "keys": 123
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "a": "foo",
      "bunch": 123,
      "of": "foo",
      "other": "foo",
      "keys": 123
    }
  ]
}
```

What I tried so far:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "contacts": {
        "*": {
          "*": "contacts[&1].&0",
          "$": "contacts[&1].id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This isn't working because the resultant `id` is another array. **`"id" : [ "idx", null ]`**

Comment: That led me down the correct path.  See answer.

Answer (score 1):

This **`shift`** spec will do it.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "contacts": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2[&1]",
          "$": "&2[&1].id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "contacts": {
        "*": {
          "id": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This will set the `id` as `string` tho, not sure if that's fine

Comment: Figured it out; needed a second transformation for `=toInteger`